# Letters choppy on Google Earth

Tags: 11.04, google-earth

I installed Google Earth and it is basically working, but the letters are choppy.

Why are the letters choppy?

[image: The letters are choppy.]

Comment: Check this topic:

This is what it worked for me:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/70167/google-earth-font-issue-on-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when I first installed Google Earth, but it was at about the same time as I installed Ubuntu 11.04.  So I installed fonts from the Ubuntu Software Center, including and especially the installer for the Microsoft TrueType fonts.  The next time I restarted the computer, it worked just fine.  I can't tell you exactly which font worked, but it seems that one of them did.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9004673) post has your answer!

Anyway, just to reiterate, open up your terminal, by using your dash search, then copy-paste the following:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

You should need to enter your password. When its done installing, type in

```
qtconfig
```

Go to "Fonts" tab.

Go to "Point Size".

Click on the dropdown menu. 
Change "9" for "14". (or whatever is comfortable for you)

Navigate the the menu FILE > SAVE.

Navigate the the menu FILE > EXIT.

There, it should work!