# google-earth font issue on installation

Tags: 11.10, fonts, google-earth

I've tried installing Google Earth on Oneric (11.10) following instructions here:
  [To do list after installing ubuntu 11.10](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/to-do-list-after-installing-ubuntu-11-10-aka-oneiric-ocelot/)

(Scroll way down or search the page for "google earth")

However with either method I end up with a very strange looking GE. I assume it is related to fonts, but I did install the mscorefonts as required by the created package.

Does anyone have suggestions?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE3Xx.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that you need to install `ttf-mstcorefonts-installer`.

If you start the application after installation you get the picture shown in your question.

However on logout and login the fonts in the application behaves correctly...

[image]

Comment: I would just add that in my case I needed to reboot after installing the fonts in order to see google earth properly.
Many thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all http://askubuntu.com/questions/225702/fix-google-earth-6-2-2-japanese-fonts

Comment: @JoshuaRobison - yours is a very different question so I'm not surprised this solution doesnt work for you.